# Does Facebook infer OpenGraph descriptions from page content when missing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

This is not my website/I have no connection to it, but I'm trying to understand how Facebook gets content using OpenGraph tags exactly - specifically, if a tag is missing does it attempt to read website content to generate one? And if so, is there a programmatic way to tell if Facebook has done this?

**The example:** [This website for a nonprofit called Hekima Place](https://www.hekimaplace.org) doesn't have an `og:description` meta tag, [as the Facebook Sharing Debugger reveals](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hekimaplace.org%2F). However, it still gets an `og:description` value and a proper description in the card, which seems to match a "What We Do" section's `<p>` tag further down on the page.

When checking [the Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger for this site](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hekimaplace.org%2F), it doesn't seem to mention that the description is inferred anywhere. Is it also possible that such a description might have been entered somewhere in a Facebook dashboard to fill in that data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, Facebook does try to extract information from the page content, if OG meta data is missing. No, there is no other place to explicitly specify it.

Comment: Though it seems that the Facebook Sharing Debugger specifically says that "Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties", which then includes `og:description` - doesn't really seem to be based on the raw tags then, should I just disregard that page's wording and assume that the found stuff may or may not be based on existent tags?

Comment: “Show All Raw Tags” shows which meta tag info Facebook actually read from the URL, everything you don’t find in there explicitly they must have gathered from other sources.